# Command 'date +FORMAT' — What are %a, %A, %b, etc. called?

Tags: date, terminology

The `date` command outputs the current date and time like this: `Fri Apr 12 15:04:03 UTC 2013`.

To have the output date-time in a custom format we can use `date +FORMAT`, for example, like this: `date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z"` which gives something like `2013-04-12T15:04:37+00:00`.

But I want to know what the `%Y`, `%m`, `%d`, `%H`, `%M`, `%S`, etc. are collectively called (i.e. the terminology). Also, what's the `T` called, as it's different from the rest?

Comment: “FORMAT controls the output.  Interpreted **sequences** are…” – man `date` And the “T” is just a literal “T”.

Comment: @manatwork In the man page, I thought the _sequences_ refer to both the `%Y` and their respective meaning.

Comment: Tip: `date +"You will die in the year %Y"`

Comment: @Izkata Makes no sense(?)

Comment: @TheoneManis Just an example of that `T` not being special.  Also, I was having a weird day at work when I typed that (listening to co-workers' conversations).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term used in the POSIX specification of the [`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) command is "conversion specifications".

The format string for the `date` command is closely based on the format string for C's `printf` function; the C standard also refers to things like `%d` as "conversion specifications".

`T` not preceded by `%` is just a character: "All other characters shall be copied to the output without change."

According to the change history section of the POSIX description of `date`:

> The DESCRIPTION is updated to refer to conversion specifications, instead of field descriptors for consistency with the LC_TIME category.

So apparently an earlier version of the specification used the phrase "field descriptors", but "conversion specifications" is the current official term.

Of course that doesn't mean you *have* to refer to them that way.

Comment: Are "`conversion sequences`" or "`format sequences`" appropriate terms too? I am considering `sequences` over `specifications` 'cause it's actually mentioned in the man page for `date`.

Comment: @TheoneManis: Any of the three seems sufficiently obvious about what it means.

Answer (score 4):

I would think "escape sequences" or (in this case) "special characters for percent-escaped sequences" would be the typical way of referring to them.  Backslash-and percent-escaped sequences are much used in C (e.g. printf), so they've filtered into several Unix-commands too (like specifying the prompt for the shell).

The "escape sequence" being "%Y", "%m", "%d" and so on; and the "special characters" being "Y", "m", "d" and so on.  "%" would be the "escape character" (the character that gives the following character an unusual/special meaning).

Answer (score 3):

[This document](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds2%2Fdate.htm) from IBM's Information Center clearly states that *the alphabets* in `%Y`, `%m`, `%d`, `%H`, `%M`, `%S`, etc. are called "**Field Descriptors**".

> You must precede each **field descriptor** with a **%** (percent sign). The system replaces the field descriptor with the specified value. [...] The `date` command copies any other characters to the output without change.

That answers my two questions (about %n & T). And I believe this is as authoritative as it can get.

Comment: IBM didn't invent the `date` command; what makes their documentation authoritative? The command's behavior is currently defined by POSIX, which doesn't use that term. The change history at the bottom of the [POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) says "The DESCRIPTION is updated to refer to conversion specifications, instead of field descriptors for consistency with the LC_TIME category.", implying that "conversion specification", not "field diescriptor" is the correct current term. See also my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, the `T` is a literal letter `T`. But to be specific, your example `date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z"` appears to be a format string conforming to the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) specification for date and time. So here the `T` is a delimiter that separates the date from the time.